# python select.epoll() not working

Tags: python, python-2.6

I build python2.6.1 on laptop. Build was successful. After that I tried to run python using ./python and tried to import select module

```
>>>import select
>>>select.epoll()
<select.epoll object at 0xb76140d0>
```

After that I copied the python build folder to anther laptop and tried to run python

```
>>>import select
>>> select.epoll()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'epoll'
```

How to solve this problem

Comment: What is the value of `select` on each?

Comment: What OS and/or Linux distro is on each laptop?

Comment: one is redhat and other is ubuntu. I would like to konw is epoll depends on some system library

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> select.epoll([sizehint=-1])
>
> *(Only supported on Linux 2.5.44 and newer.)*
>   Returns an edge polling object, which can be used as Edge or Level Triggered interface
>   for I/O events; see section Edge and Level Trigger Polling (epoll)
>   Objects below for the methods supported by epolling objects.
>
> New in version 2.6.

And obviously distromakers can disable it in python build settings or so. It does depend on glibc only as far as I know. Also are you sure you are importing from the system select module, and not from your own module named by the same name? (check `select.__file__`; as a builtin module it should not have a file ;)

Comment: I dont have any other select module and select.__file__ is giving me python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/select.so